# How to reverse a map in Kotlin using immutable transformation

Tags: kotlin

I have a following Kotlin map and I want to reverse the map, for the duplicated new key, the value will be appended to a list.

```
val map = Map(1 to 111, 2 to 222, 3 to 111)
```

After the conversion, the result map is

```
Map(111 to List(1,3), 222 to 2)
```

PS: I did work out a way of doing it by creating a mutable map and iterate the existing map. But I more look for a immutable way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can group map entries by their value selecting key from each entry:

```
    val map = mapOf(1 to 111, 2 to 222, 3 to 111)

    val reversed = map.entries.groupBy({ it.value }, { it.key })

    println(reversed) // prints: {111=[1, 3], 222=[2]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat way to do it without using mutable collections, with [`groupingBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) and more importantly, [`aggregate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/aggregate.html):

```
val map: Map<Int, Int> = mapOf(1 to 111, 2 to 222, 3 to 111)

val result: Map<Int, List<Int>> = map.entries
        .groupingBy { it.value }
        .aggregate { key: Int, accumulator: List<Int>?, element: Map.Entry<Int, Int>, first: Boolean ->                
            if (first) {
                listOf(element.key)
            } else {
                accumulator!! + element.key
            }
        }
```

You could also ignore the `first` parameter and use null handling to decide whether you already have an accumulator, and of course in either case, you don't need to explicitly type the parameters:

```
val result: Map<Int, List<Int>> = map.entries
        .groupingBy { it.value }
        .aggregate { key, accumulator, element, first ->
            accumulator?.plus(element.key) ?: listOf(element.key)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
fun reverse(map: Map<Int, Int>): Map<Int, List<Int>> {
  val mm = mutableMapOf<Int, List<Int>>()
  map.forEach { k, v -> mm[v] = mm.getOrDefault(v, listOf()) + k }

  return mm
}
```

It will leave you with a List for all map values, but it does reverse the map.

Comment: Thanks, I think i didn't describe it clearly. I more look for a immutable way of doing it.

Comment: More than just converting the `MutableMap` to a Map after the fact?

Comment: @ttt what did you mean under `immutable way of doing it`? while the target map populated with transformed values it have to be mutable.